# Datatables Buttons to show/hide RowGroups

Tags: r, shiny, datatables

I have a table that uses RowGroups and Buttons/Colvis.

Much like the buttons for Colvis, I'd like to have buttons to show only specific RowGroups. Currently I have a long table with quite a few RowGroups. Often users will want to see only specific column groups and I'd like to prevent them from having to scroll down all the way constantly.

From the examples below, imagine there being a button "Row group" visibility, exactly like the Column visiblity in Colvis.

[image: Example, imagine there also being a "Row visibility" button.]

Comment: Do you want them collapsible? Or just completely hidden?

Comment: Either is fine, but completely hidden would be the best. Collapsible would cause someone to have to hide numerous groups quite often, where hiding them all through one button is a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I described  can be accomplished using the SearchPanes extension. You can select your searchPanes targets on the same columns as your rowGroup targets.

You can also set your searchPanes to be a button.

Example from my code, with use in renderDT:

```
output$tbl <- renderDT({
        datatable(data,
                  rownames = FALSE,
                  caption = 'Some caption',
                  extensions = c('ColReorder', 'RowGroup', "Buttons",
                                 "Select", "SearchPanes"),
                  options = list(#DOM options
                                 dom = "Bfrtip",
                                 #Rowgroup options
                                 rowGroup = list(dataSrc = c(0,2)),
                                 #Buttons options
                                 stateSave = TRUE,
                                 buttons = c('colvis', 'csv', 'excel', 'searchPanes'),
                                 #ColReorder options
                                 colReorder = TRUE,
                                 #SearchPanes options
                                 columnDefs = list(
                                   list(searchPanes = list(show = FALSE), targets = 1:7)),
                                 selection = 'none',
                                 #Overige options
                                 paging = FALSE)
      )}, server = FALSE)
```

Also credit to Matt Herman's blog post: https://mattherman.info/blog/dt_searchpanes/